# Google not showing up Rich Snippets any more?

Tags: rich-snippets

Recently I was trying to implement Rich Snippets for google (for music) to show up in search results, but noticed, that Google is not showing up those rich snippets even for those web-sites, that are included in guides and examples right in google docs.

As I realize, google is showing snippets only for Youtube videos, some other video services and Blogs that are connected to Google+ now.

What's happening, google has disavowed using rich snippets, or that's country or user settings specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly showing now. However, it seems Google is regularly making changes in rich snippets feature. Sometimes you would find some pages of your site show rich snippets, while others lose. Sometimes your home page shows snippets and then it is gone. Earlier, several  thumbnails of same author were showing on a single results page. But now we see only a single post link with thumbnail of an author. It seems they would keep making changes in this feature before the feature matures a little.